# Adjoints on power sets and a connection to quantifiers as adjoints

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, lo.logic, adjoint-functors

While working through the Awodey book on Category Theory, we stumbled upon exercise 9.8.
The situation there is that you have $f : A \to B$ in Sets, and consider $\text{im}\, f : \mathcal P (A) \to \mathcal P (B)$ in PoSets (ordered by $\subseteq$).
The exercise then asks you to verify that $\text{im}\,f \dashv f^{-1}[\cdot] \dashv f_*$ are adjoint.

Note that we can write all of these as follows:

$$\text{im}\,f(A) = \{b \in B \mid \exists  a \in f^{-1}[\{b\}] : a \in A\}$$
$$f_*(A) = \{b \in B \mid \forall a \in f^{-1}[\{b\}] : a \in A\}$$
$$f^{-1}[B] = \{a \in A \mid f(a) \in B\}$$

We noted, however, that you can compare this to the adjoints $\exists \dashv \star \dashv \forall$ on first-order formulas, where $\star$ means adding a free variable.
In particular, see that $\text{im}\,f$ and $f_*$ are defined analogously, and that $\text{im}\,f$ as the left adjoint uses the $\exists$ quantifier, while $f_*$ as the right adjoint uses $\forall$.

Is there a deeper connection here?
Can we perhaps find some correspondence between $f^{-1}[\cdot]$ and adding free variables?
Do adjoints simply correspond to quantifying in general?

Thanks!

Comment: This connection was explored extensively by Lawvere: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantification#lawvere_quantifiers_quantification_as_adjunction